# No input devices working after startup

Tags: windows-7, usb, io

It's a normal day. I start my PC and try to login and BAM. Both my keyboard and mouse are not working. The devices itself are working fine (I can see the lights and stuff) but Windows somehow doesnt respond to them. Switching USB ports doesnt help. Trying out a PS/2 keyboard and mouse instead of USB doesnt help.
I'm scared, everything is stored on thay computer and I need it for school. Is there a way to fix this?

EDIT: I have confirmed the device DO work in the BIOS, at least the keyboard, so it's something with windows...

EDIT 2: Buttons like Numlock and Capslock do not work, even on the keyboard itself (The lights don't switch on and off).

Comment: Obvious question maybe but have you tried a **different** USB keyboard?

Comment: Yes. No USB devices are recognized (although I have only tried with Keyboards and Mouses). Switching ports also doesn't work.